# Panel behind panel is visible even though the first panel has Alpha set to 255

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Look at this image, you can clearly see that the panel "Panel" is still visible even though it is behind "PanelSettings":

[image]

If I change the order in the menue left then it is invisible:

[image]

But as soon as I change the position of "Panel" and move it in front of "PanelSettings" then I get another weird glitch:

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

Canvas_Settings:

[image]

GIF:
[image: <iframe src="https://giphy.com/embed/l4Ep8gMSjZJ6u21Ww" width="480" height="270" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/l4Ep8gMSjZJ6u21Ww">via GIPHY</a></p>]

Menues:

[image]

Comment: What Render Mode is your Canvas set to?

Comment: @Programmer, it is set to world space, i need it like this.

Comment: Also show the screenshot of the Canvas's settings in the Hierarchy tab. By the way, how are you moving this panel?

Comment: Ok I added a screenshot of the canvas settings. I am moving the panel by draging on the arrows.

Comment: Can you select the Menues object and post the Hierarchy screenshot too?

Comment: Ok done. Maybe this is normal behaviour? But it looks extremly weird.

Comment: You want the red object to be in the front or back?

Comment: I want it in front. I achieved it, I am just wondering about the weird glitch. The red panel is always in front as you can see in the gif, is that normal?

Comment: this is an expected UI behaviour because they are on the same canvas and the last child always gets rendered last (on top of all the other), if you wanted to play with the z position to see either one of the two in front you can create another world space canvas with the same soritng layer and order in layer and move the other panel there and then you would see the change in the game view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it in front. I achieved it, I am just wondering about the weird
>   glitch. The red panel is always in front as you can see in the gif, is
>   that normal?

That's normal and it's not a glitch. The default UI shader is made to do that so that you can easily find where UI objects are when creating, modifying and positioning them. Note that this only happens in the Scene View. You'll not see this effect in the Game View. It's just there to help you.

As for the screenshot in your question, the Object you are moving is on top of the other object(Panel), so Unity is always trying to keep that object you are moving behind the other one is under it in the Hierarchy tab. This is how Objects under Canvas function. All these work are done by the UI/Default Shader the UI is using.